# React Redux: dispatch returning data to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component with a form that will add an item. When the form is submitted I'm dispatching an async action using redux, something like this:

```
_onSubmit(event) {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const { data } = this.state;
    event.preventDefault();

    dispatch(addItem(data));
  }
```

Now, my back-end will create a task with an id that I can track progress. Usually this given task will take a while to complete, so I want to show the notification bar.

For me to track that task, I need to retrieve the task id for this given task that is in progress. So I thought about adding a callback function so that I could get this information from the dispatcher, something like this:

```
_onSubmit(event) {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        const { data } = this.state;
        event.preventDefault();

        dispatch(addItem(data, (id) => console.log(id)));
      }
```

But this feels kind of "hacky" as there is a two-way data communication going on.

**Question**: What is the redux way of achieving this?

Comment: So your endpoints is sending out a response immediately once its received the posts request with the id of the task?

Comment: Yes! Or almost immediately

Comment: Ok, so the process is something like:
1. fething_task_Id 
2. taskId_fetched_successfully //Loading, task running somewhere in the background
3. task_finished // Data //Render data

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple ways to achieve the same results for this problem.

I would say use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#installation)(Middleware), which will enable you to fire multiple actions from your action creator.

Then you should write something like this:

```
_onSubmit(event) {
 const { dispatch } = this.props;
 const { data } = this.state;
 event.preventDefault();

 dispatch(addItemActionCreator(data));
}
```

In your action creator, use a promise(as thunk will allow you to do that as well):

```
export const addItemActionCreator = (data) => (dispatch) => {
 Promise.get('data').then((data) => {
  dispatch({ type: STORE_DATA_ID, id: data.id })
 })
}
```

This will dispatch an action that will store id, in your state.

In your component, use `connect` to subscribe to `id` and your component will always have the latest `id` value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm already using thunk. Unfortunately I believe your answer does not solve my problem. There can be multiple tasks running, how do I know from the array of ids which one belongs to me? My object (data) does not have anything inside it that is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Why not to add something unique inside data object?

Comment: so, for you to track different ids, you will have constant action types which only update one portion of your state and thats how you will know the specific id.
You will have to dispatch different actions to store different ids in different portion of your state, otherwise they will overlap and your constant(action type) will give you control over which portion of the state to update and then you can just subscribe that portion of the state
I hope this helps.

Comment: @elmeister I'm starting to lean towards that solution. For edit and delete I have the object id, so no problem. So I guess I will have to set a temp id for the add scenario, maybe current time in milliseconds. But this feels way more complex than just have the id callback :(

Comment: For me too - I would use the id callback :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to achieve this. I've done something very similar using [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/) with [eventChannels](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md#using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events).

You could also use [redux-cycles](https://github.com/cyclejs-community/redux-cycles) or [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/) for the same purpose: creating an observable that's subscribed to the signals of your API, and that it dispatches actions as they come.

I am not a fan of redux-thunk. Maybe there could be a way to accomplish this using redux-thunk, but I'm quite certain that it won't be easy/elegant.